# CSS3 animation to start only when page is scrolled to the right place

Tags: html5, css3, animated

I want to show an CSS3 animation with a delay, but it is below the fold of the page, meaning, that animation may start and end before user scrolls to the area where it should perform.

How can I set up to start the animation when a container DIV gets visible for the user when he scrolls down to this DIV?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **programming** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Programming questions may be asked at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery (or make it plain JS) to add a class when a certain point has been reached.

```
var classHadBeenAdded = false;
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
    if( !classHadBeenAdded  && $(document).scrollTop() < foldValue ){
        $('#element').addClass('ClassWithAnimation');
        classHadBeenAdded = true; // save change so it doesnt double.
    }
});
```

You might want to add a dethrottle to it to prevent the number of calls jamming your browser.

---

Another method is a variant, make `transition-delay` something very high, and change that value with JS upon the triggerpoint.

Comment: In your example, `classHadBeenAdded` is just a local variable, so it can't be used to maintain state between calls, as you seem to be doing.